# Accessing HTML buttons

Tags: vb.net

There are 17 HTML buttons on a website. These Buttons are without ID and have same name,type and value. I want to click the Buttons programatically by using vb.net 2008 webbrowser control. When i write this code

```
Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        WebBrowser1.Navigate("website bla bla")
    End Sub

    Private Sub WebBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs) Handles WebBrowser1.DocumentCompleted

        Dim allelements As HtmlElementCollection = WebBrowser1.Document.All

        For Each webpageelement As HtmlElement In allelements

            If webpageelement.GetAttribute("value") =  "Start" Then

                webpageelement.InvokeMember("click")

            End If

        Next

    End Sub
End Class
```

Then each time, the 17th button is clicked by my program. Where i want to click the 1st button individually , the 2nd button , the 3rd button and so on the next buttons individually each. So can you please guide me how to click each button individually. Here is the HTML Code of the buttons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your last button gets clicked because all buttons have, as you claim, the same value.  Hence you should not identify the button by value.

The best solution would be to modify the server side so that the buttons have some property (ideally the `id`) that makes it easy to distinguish them from each other programmatically. (This would apply, for example, if you are writing a test harness for a web site that your colleagues develop.  Talk to them and call your request "testability".)

However, if you absolutely have to work with the website as is, there is one bit of information that makes each button unique and that is its sequential index.

```
Dim i As Integer
Dim allButtons As HtmlElementCollection

allButtons = WebBrowser1.Document.getElementsByTagName('input');

i = 0
For Each webpageelement As HtmlElement In allButtons
    i += 1
    If i = 7 Then
        webpageelement.InvokeMember("click")
    End If
Next
```

This will click the seventh's button.  The drawback of this method is that every time the layout of the website changes a little, your client code will break down severely causing all kinds of confusion and tedium before it is fixed.  You can partly fight that by representing these fixed index values with symbolic names and comparing any sequential indexes only to those, but it is still a fragile technique with difficult reusability.

Comment: Stack Overflow is not an interactive debugging service.

Comment: @ChauhdryKing - Let's respect the moderator decision and stick to Q+A format of the site.  Good questions generally get good answers from the community very, very quickly.  Separate questions should be entered as separate, standalone questions.